Can a real valued, continuous, non-periodic function have a periodic definite integral?
More precisely, does there exist a continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ where $f(x_1)\neq f(x_1+nx_2)$, with $g(x):=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ periodic? This was just a question that popped into my head today while I was thinking about oscillating functions. Maybe it is trivial or ill-posed?

If $g$ is periodic then so is $f$, for $$f(x+T)=g'(x+T)=\lim\frac{g(x+T+h)-g(x+T)}h=$$$$\lim\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}h=g'(x)=f(x)$$ where $T$ is the period of $g$.
